# Can we avoid using SIP library when writing standalone QGIS python script

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, sip

I wanted to write a small custom python script using QGIS functionality. So I started with the [QGIS documentation](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html) on the custom application section.

After having some troubles with the `import qgis.core` statement, which I could fix, I ran into the error message

```
ImportError: No module named sip
```

This one made me somewhat of a headache, as you could see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30004778/no-module-named-sip-when-running-qgis-from-python).

As I could not fix this one, I wonder why it's so much of a problem. Also, the doc states

> "PyQGIS bindings depend on SIP and PyQt4."

So I wonder, why it actually complains. Shouldn't it then come with the QGIS distribution? (Actually, there is a sip folder containing PyQT4 folder and also a sip.exe. But this does not seem to be of any effect.)

After all, my question is, is it possible to work around it, getting QGIS python running without SIP?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No you can't.  The Python bindings need `sip` so you will have to get it working.  However it is included with QGIS so if your getting that error something isn't setup right.

When ever I create a standalone QGIS Python application (on Window at least) I use the following batch file:

```
REM Change OSGeo4W_ROOT to point to your install of QGIS.

SET OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\OSGeo4W
SET QGISNAME=qgis
SET QGIS=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\%QGISNAME%
set QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=%QGIS%

CALL "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\o4w_env.bat"

: Python Setup
set PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin;%QGIS%\bin;%PATH%
SET PYTHONHOME=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python27
set PYTHONPATH=%QGIS%\python;%PYTHONPATH%

ECHO OSGeo path is: %OSGEO4W_ROOT%
ECHO Getting QGIS libs from: %QGIS%
ECHO Python loaded from: %PYTHONHOME%

python myscript.py
```

You need to change `OSGEO4W_ROOT` to point to the base of your QGIS install. This is just the top level folder e.g `C:\Program Files (x86)\QGIS Valmiera` everything else in that script is relative to that root folder.

Comment: Thanks for that idea. The bat script seems to run fine, setting everything (as I can see from the echos). Nevertheless, my python script than complains `No module named qgis.core`. I have to call sys.path.extend([r"C:\Program Files (x86)\QGIS Valmiera\apps\qgis\python"]) explicitly and then end up again with `No module named sip`.

Comment: You don't have to do sys.path.extend. If you are getting no `qgis.core` the batch isn't 100% yet.

Comment: Try the updated script. If it doesn't work, paste what you are using.  Did you replace the `OSGEO4W_ROOT` variable.

Comment: Yes, I replaced it. Interestingly, now your script runs without complaining from the cmd. If I call it using `subprocess.call('path/to/bat-script', shell=True)` from my python script, I still get the same `no qgis.core`. what's the difference here...?

Comment: Why are you calling it like that?

Comment: Because I want to execute my .py script from the IDE actually and having done everything (like setting the correct path setup inside there).

Comment: Maybe I'll get that working. Still, I can test it by running from cmd first. Anyway, your response did more than answer my question.